# Wildfly - How to install as domain mode on Windows

Tags: java, jboss, configuration, windows-services, wildfly

I managed to run `Wildfly` on `Ubuntu` in domain mode but I am having troubles in `Windows`. Here is my setup and steps:

1. I have two Windows servers (say, `S1` and `S2`) on which Wildfly is going to run as `Windows service`
2. I have `domain.xml`, `host-master.xml`, and `host-slave.xml` files. On Linux, I update the `/etc/default/wildfly` file to tell the S1 server that it is going to be the `master` and S2 is going to be the `slave`. The master and slave configurations are in `host-master.xml` and `host-slave.xml` files. So basically, I tell S1 to use host-master and S2 to host-slave. If I add S3 server, I tell it to use host-slave with appropriate configuration.
3. On Linux, after telling Wildfly which xml file to use, I install them as Linux services. This is what I want to do on Windows
4. I cd to `wildfly\bin\service` directory
5. This is the code I used for master: `service install /controller S1:9990 /host master /user user /password pass`
6. This is for slave: `service install /controller S1:9990 /host slave /user user /password pass`

But as you can guess, although I can login into admin console, I cannot see the slave. Only master is present. Besides, when I try to login to admin console on S2, I still can see the console with the master configuration.

I am missing something for sure but I don't know what it is. Can you please help?

My host-master.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<host name="S1" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="host-file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.domain.data.dir"/>
                <file-handler name="server-file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="host-file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <server-logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="server-file"/>
                </handlers>
            </server-logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <domain-controller>
        <local/>
    </domain-controller>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <any-address/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <jvms>
        <jvm name="default">
            <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
            <permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
            <jvm-options>
                <option value="-server"/>
            </jvm-options>
        </jvm>
    </jvms>

    <servers>
        <server name="solr-server" group="solr_server" auto-start="false">
            <socket-bindings socket-binding-group="full-sockets" port-offset="983"/>
        </server>
        <server name="80-8200" group="edys-web-servers" auto-start="false">
            <socket-bindings socket-binding-group="full-sockets" port-offset="199"/>
        </server>
</servers>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>
</host>
```

My host-slave.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<host name="S2" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <secret value="UGFzc3cwcmQ="/>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="host-file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.domain.data.dir"/>
                <file-handler name="server-file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="host-file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <server-logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="server-file"/>
                </handlers>
            </server-logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
            </native-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <domain-controller>
        <remote security-realm="ManagementRealm" username="ebys">
            <discovery-options>
                <static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:remote}" host="${jboss.domain.master.address:S1}" 
                port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}"/>
            </discovery-options>
        </remote>
    </domain-controller>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:S2}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:S2}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:S2}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <jvms>
        <jvm name="default">
            <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
            <permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
            <jvm-options>
                <option value="-server"/>
            </jvm-options>
        </jvm>
    </jvms>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>
</host>
```

PS: There is a bug on Windows that I cannot stop the Wildfly service. I have to restart the server (service is in manual mode) and then uninstall the service. Therefore, I cannot just uninstall and install the service without restarting the server first. There is a bug reported about this but unfortunately the suggestions does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run WildFly as a service

Before strating WildFly as a service, there should be defined an environment variable:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Djboss.bind.address=<local bind address> -Djboss.bind.address.management=<management bind address> -Djboss.domain.master.address=<address of the domain controller>
```

**ATTENTION!!! For WildFly 10 needs to add additional variable: jboss.bind.address.private=< address of the server in cluster >**

Powershell:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_OPTS", "-Djboss.bind.address=<local bind address> -Djboss.bind.address.management=<management bind address> -Djboss.domain.master.address=<address of the domain controller>", "Machine")
```

The last parameter "jboss.domain.master.address" - needs only for slave nodes.

Windows service can be installed by the script inside 
< wildfly_home_dir >/bin/service:

Master node

```
service.bat install /host master
```

Slave node

```
service.bat install /controller <domain_conroller_address>:9990 /host <slave_host_name> /user <admin_user_to_domain_controller> /password <admin_password_to_domain_controller>
```

For the slave nodes needs to change a system registry key (activate slave mode config):

regedit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Wildfly\Parameters\Start
Params:REG_MULTI_SZ
/c "set NOPAUSE=Y && domain.bat --host-config=host-slave.xml"
```

2. Define security credentials for the management

On the domain-controller node add a new user for slave nodes (can be one user for all nodes). Interactive command-line script - add_user[.bat].

After finishing - it will print XML tag with the password on console (< secret value...). This should be copied and inserted into the host-slave.xml file on the slave node (user name should be added to the tag host/domain-controller/remote as an attribute "username":

host-slave.xml

```
<host xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0" name="slave">
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <secret value="MQ=="/>
                </server-identities>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
    </management>
    <domain-controller>
        <remote security-realm="ManagementRealm" username="slave">
            <discovery-options>
                <static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:remote}" host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}"/>
            </discovery-options>
        </remote>
    </domain-controller>
</host>
```

3. Start master node
4. Configure HornetMQ/ActiveMQ cluster password

jboss-cli

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default:write-attribute(name=cluster-password,value="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}")
```

The other way is to define a system environment variable for all WildFly nodes in full-ha configuration: jboss.messaging.cluster.password (could be done in the management UI inteface after starting domain controller).

5.Start slave nodes

Comment: Service is installed successfully on master but on restarting its stuck on stopping

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use https://github.com/tfonteyn/jboss7service.bat
service script for EAP6/AS7/WildFly8+ as it also has support for domain mode.

all you need separately is apache prunsrv.exe which you can get from: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/binaries.html

I would recommend to read the comments in [service.bat](https://github.com/tfonteyn/jboss7service.bat/blob/master/service.bat) to get some ideas what are the options and how to use it.